# How can I return to URL query, after submitting in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, razor-pages

After spending a couple of days, searching for a solution, I have to ask for your help, as I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

As with the last question I had in here, I have been following a course on Udemy.com about ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages, and With some changes I have managed to create my little own project, but has now ran in to an issue that I hope you can help me solve.

In short, I have a RepairList where the user can press an a tag, and the list then sorts the repairs matching that specific RepairTeam.
The user can then access each repair, and update it. After the update, it returns to the list. But here is the problem. Instead of just returning to the specific teams repairs, it returns to all repairs.
E.g. if Electrician is selected, and a repair for him is updated, it returns to All instead of Electrician.
How can I return to Electrician?

Here is my HTML for RepairList:

```
<div class="border backgroundWhite container">


<div class="col-12">
    <h2 class="text-darkblue">Repair List</h2>
</div>
<div class="row col-12 col-sm-8 offset-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-evenly justify-content-sm-end">
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="all">
            <span class="list-group-item text-truncate @all">All</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="electrician">
            <span class="list-group-item text-truncate @electrician">Electrician</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="carpenter">
            <span class=" list-group-item text-truncate @carpenter">Carpenter</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="plumber">
            <span class="list-group-item text-truncate @plumber">Plumber</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row col-12 col-sm-8 offset-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-evenly justify-content-sm-end mb-3">
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="gom">
            <li class="list-group-item text-truncate @gom">GOM</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="engine">
            <li class="list-group-item text-truncate @engine">Engine</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="deck">
            <li class="list-group-item text-truncate @deck">Deck</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-0 m-1" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); width:22%;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none;" asp-page="RepairList" asp-route-team="accommodation">
            <li class="list-group-item text-truncate @accommodation">Accommodation</li>
        </a>
    </div>        
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch float-sm-end float-start m-2 mb-4">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="allRepairsSwitch" name="allRepairsSwitch">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="allRepairsSwitch">  &nbsp; Include done repairs</label>
</div>
<label hidden="hidden" type="text" id="isToggled"></label>

<table id="DT_load" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Repair Type</th>
            @*<th>Deck</th>*@
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Done</th>
            @*<th>Done By</th>*@
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And here is my code behind for RepairList:

```
public class RepairListModel : PageModel
{
    
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        
            return Page();
    }
}
```

My javaScript file looks like this:

```
var dataTable;
var toggled = document.getElementById("isToggled").textContent;

//Load List of repairs when document is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {

    
    toggled = "false";
    var url = window.location.search;
    if (url.includes("electrician")) {
        loadList("Electrician");
    }
    else {
        if (url.includes("carpenter")) {
            loadList("Carpenter");
        }
        else {
            if (url.includes("plumber")) {
                loadList("Plumber");
            }
            else {
                if (url.includes("gom")) {
                    loadList("GOM");
                }
                else {
                    if (url.includes("engine")) {
                        loadList("Engine");
                    }
                    else {
                        if (url.includes("deck")) {
                            loadList("Deck");
                        }
                        else {
                            if (url.includes("accommodation")) {
                                loadList("Accommodation")
                            }
                            else {
                                loadList("");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (toggled == "false") {
        dataTable.column(6).search('^$', true, false).draw();
    }
    else {
        dataTable.column(6).search("").draw();
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#allRepairsSwitch').change(function () {
        document.getElementById("isToggled").textContent = $(this).prop('checked');
        if (document.getElementById("isToggled").textContent == "false") {
            dataTable.column(6).search('^$', true, false).draw();
        }
        else {
            dataTable.column(6).search("").draw();
        }
    });
});

function loadList(param) {
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/repair?team=" + param,
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },        
        "columns": [
            { "data": "createdDate", "width": "12%" },
            { "data": "team.name", "width": "8%" },
            { "data": "repairType.name", "width": "10%" },
            /*{ "data": "deck.name", "width": "10%" },*/
            { "data": "place", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "description", "width": "23%" },
            { "data": "comment", "width": "10%"  },
            { "data": "doneDate", "width": "12%" },
            //{
            //    "data": null,
            //    "render": function (data) {
            //        return repairedBy(data);                   
            //    },
            //    "width": "10%"                
            //},
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return ` <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Admin/repair/repairDetails?id=${data}" class="btn btn-edit" style="cursor:pointer; width:100px;">
                                    <i class="far fa-edit"></i> Details
                                </a>
                    </div>`;
                }, "width": "10%"
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0, 6],
                /*"type": "date-eu",*/
                "render": function (data, type) {
                    if (data !== null) {
                        //var javascriptDate = moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
                        //javascriptDate = ("0" + javascriptDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (javascriptDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + javascriptDate.getFullYear() + " " + ("0"+javascriptDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0"+javascriptDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
                        return type == 'sort' ? data : moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": [1, 2, 3, 5],
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(12, true)
            },
            {
                "targets": [4],
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(40, true)
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "no data found."
        },
        "width": "100%",
        "responsive": true,
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        'rowCallback': function (row, data, index) {
            if (data.comment !== null && data.doneDate == null) {
                $(row).css('color', '#ed8b00');
            }
            else {
                $(row).css('color', '#002b45');
            }
        },
        "dom": "Bfrtip",
        "buttons": ['excel', 'print'],
    });
}
```

And I have a controller like this:

```
namespace ShipWorks.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RepairController : Controller
    {
        //Dependency Injection to get the data from the database
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public RepairController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(string team = null)
        {
            if (team == SD.TeamElectrician)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamElectrician, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamCarpenter)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamCarpenter, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamPlumber)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamPlumber, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamGom)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamGom, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamEngine)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamEngine, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamDeck)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamDeck, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            if (team == SD.TeamAccommodation)
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(r => r.Team.Name == SD.TeamAccommodation, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Repair.GetAll(null, null, "Deck,RepairType,Team,ApplicationUser") });
            }
        }
```

Then the RepairDetails HTML is a bit longer, so I am going to spare you for that, as I do not think it is needed, but the Update button looks like this:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-edit form-control" onclick="return ValidateUpdateInput()">
                                <i class="fas fa-save"></i> &nbsp; Update
                            </button>
```

And the code behind:

```
 public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RepairObj.TeamList = _unitofWork.Team.GetTeamListForDropDown();
                RepairObj.RepairTypeListByTeam = _unitofWork.RepairType.GetRepairTypeListForDropDownByTeam();
                RepairObj.DeckList = _unitofWork.Deck.GetDeckListForDropDown();
                RepairObj.UserList = _unitofWork.ApplicationUser.GetUserListForDropDown();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {            
                _unitofWork.Repair.Update(RepairObj.Repair);
                _unitofWork.Save();
                
                return RedirectToPage("./RepairList");

            }
        }
```

If I "hard code" the return to:

```
return RedirectToPage("./RepairList", new { team = "electrician" });
```

it works, but of course only if you are electrician. :-)
So I feel I am close, but still so far from.
Can anyone help?

I do apologize if I have added to much or to little code. I will be happy to supply you with any extra information.

Comment: I am not experienced with Razor, but I think something like: `return RedirectToPage("./RepairList", new { team = _unitofWork.Team.Name });` should do it?

Comment: @Luuk I tried that and it did not work. Also RepairObj.Repair.Team.Name is not working. But thanks for taking your time to answer. :-)

Comment: There should be 'some' local variable which hold the name of the team on which you are currently filtering....

Comment: @Luuk that is what I am thinking. It should be so easy, but I just can work it out.